# What is more popular - CSS fixed page width or flexible, what is most popular page resolution - 970 or 1024 px

Tags: html, css, xhtml

What is more popular these days - CSS fixed page width or flexible, how are the pages built in terms of CSS views layouts

what is most popular page resolution - 970 or 1024 px

Answer (score 2):

Make it flexible and save yourself the headaches in the future.  Pick a minimum size you're going to support, and make sure it scales.

If you make it fixed, it only looks good for a fraction of the people.

And, just because a person has a high resolution, doesn't mean the browser window will be maximized.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find that if a site is fixed, it will most likely be designed for a screen width of 1024px, meaning the width of the contain will be around 960px.

This article does a good job summerizing some pros and cons of both approaches: [Fixed vs. Fluid vs. Elastic Layout: What’s The Right One For You?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)
.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely make it fixed. As a 1920x1200 user, 100% width pages hurt my eyes badly - I'm talking to you wikipedia.
Notable exceptions are [igoogle](http://www.google.com/ig), where you really need all the screen space you can have.

There is a reason most sites go for fixed layout. You should really do the same unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: 100% width pages are bad, i agree with you at this, but fixed is same bad. With fixed styled pages you're disabling user to set it's own font, font size. What i don't like. I suppose that good will be using of ems, because this is related to font size, which makes page good looking for people which have big font and small resolution and also for people which are using small fonts.

Comment: You can code fluid and have it look good in both.  Just have a min and max width on the content, keeping it centered.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding popular resolutions, I would suggest examining your site with [Google Browser Size](http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Know our audience is better.

1. [Global Web Stats](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)
2. [Browser Display Statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)

I choose [960](http://960.gs/) with fixed layout

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bit of a subjective question because I doubt most of us here will know what's trully more popular (or where those statistics might be).

Stack Overflow, for example, uses a fixed layout and most of the corporate sites I've worked on have been fixed width also.

My personal preference is for fixed layout. Partly because it keeps everything contained in a way I find preferable and partly because it means I can choose the page width myself based on my own preference in the moment (I tend to use CTRL +/- a lot daily).

As for what *you* should do, it depends on what you want to acheive, what you prefer, what your customers/users may find more usable etc.

Comment: ok, you seem to have answered the question - that fixed is more popular , what is the fixed width and resolution that you are using most often, do you consider mobile readers thereby